# How can I detect if a player doesn't wear a diamond chestplate?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-data-packs

I'm making a datapack that makes a new enchantment. and I didn't find a way to detect if player does *not* wear a diamond chestplate with predicate. if someone knows what should I do please answer.

me and my friends did it we found a way.

Comment: What was the way you found? Please post it as an answer instead of leaving!

Comment: I used a command block that reversed the signal, and I made a function that spawns it at spawn at y=3 inside a bedrock box

Answer (score 0):

as simple as follows:

[image]

the purple command block has:

```
/execute as @a[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond_chestplate",Slot:102b}]}] run help
```

basically, the command block will turn on the comparator when someone has a chestplate, and we can just flip the signal.

[image]

Comment: It is highly not recommended to mix commands and redstone. I'd like to encourage you to find a way involving non-redstone usage.